# Youtube Stats for Nerds: What does the (137/140) behind "DASH: yes" stand for?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, mpeg-dash

Youtube shows some more or less informative things if you rightclick on a video and choose "Stats for Nerds".
Unfortunately, I could't find any documentation for the fields shown.

Depending on your configuration, it might be that it streams using MPEG Dash and it looks similar to the following screenshot. But what does the "(137/140)" stand for?

[image: Youtube Stats for Nerds]

PS: in case someone is wondering: the "codecs"-string seems to be specified by [RFC6381](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6381)

Comment: This is not really a programming question, it's a question about the YouTube player.

Comment: Well... it depends a bit on what you're programming ;-) Please file it as a curious question on their DASH implementation. Bet let's not get meta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are itag values that refer to different video and/or audio formats. The first number corresponds to video and the second to audio. You can actually see these numbers change when you select different resolution from the player's settings.

Many but probably not all of the itags are documented in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_formats)